# Windows authentication not working when deployed MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I have configured my MVC site to use windows authentication in the project properties and in the config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

When I run the code on my machine everything works fine but when I deploy the site to IIS i get an error stating "User . You are not authorized to use this website."

I made sure Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS features, not sure what else I should to for this to work, please help!

- .NET Framework 4.5
- IIS 7.5
- MVC 5

[image: Windows Auth enabled in IIS...]

[image: Web project properties]

Comment: Is the IIS server in the same domain?

Comment: could you please check your .Net Authorization Rules of IIS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to disable your anonymous authentication.

Comment: Disable the anonymous authentication in IIS>> Under the authentication